# Why is socket path length limited to a hundred chars?

Tags: filenames, socket, limit, unix-sockets

On Unix systems path names have usually virtually no length limitation (well, 4096 characters on Linux)... except for socket files paths which are limited to [around 100 characters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_un.h.html#tag_13_67_04) (107 characters on [Linux](https://linux.die.net/man/7/unix)).

- First question: **why such a low limitation?**

I've checked that it seems possible to work around this limitation by changing the current working directory and creating in various directories several socket files all using the same path `./myfile.sock`: the client applications seem to correctly connect to the expected server processes even-though `lsof` shows all of them listening on the same socket file path.

- Is this workaround reliable or was I just lucky?
- Is this behavior specific to Linux or may this workaround be applicable to other Unixes as well?

Comment: The limit is even lower (104) on current OpenBSD systems or Mac OS X 10.11.

Comment: The important thing, is that it has to be lower than 108, for the sake of compatibility :)

Comment: AFAIK it's 108 chars on Linux. Please check /usr/include/$arch-linux-gnu/sys/un.h on your machine.

Comment: @schaiba: 108 bytes, which means a 107 characters string ended by a null terminator.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Compatibility with other platforms, or compatibility with older stuff to avoid overruns while using `snprintf()` and `strncpy()`.

Michael Kerrisk explain in [his book](http://man7.org/tlpi/index.html) at the [page 1165](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=2SAQAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA1165&ots=qQy2bbDAsv&dq=SUSv3%20doesn%E2%80%99t%20specify%20the%20size%20of%20the%20sun_path%20field.%20Early%20BSD%20implementations%20used%20108%20and%20104%20bytes%2C%20and%20one%20contemporary%20implementation%20(HP-UX%2011)%20uses%2092&hl=pt-BR&pg=PA1165#v=onepage&q&f=false) - Chapter 57, Sockets: Unix domain :

> SUSv3 doesn’t specify the size of the sun_path field. Early BSD implementations used 108 and 104 bytes, and one contemporary implementation (HP-UX 11) uses 92 bytes. Portable applications should code to this lower value, and use snprintf() or strncpy() to avoid buffer overruns when writing into this field.

Docker guys even made fun of it, because some sockets were 110 characters long:

- [lol 108 chars ETOOMANY](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/13408)

This is why LINUX uses a 108 char socket. Could this be changed? Of course. And this, is the reason why in the first place this limitation was created on older Operating Systems:

- [Why is the maximal path length allowed for unix-sockets on linux 108?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34829600/2231796)

Quoting the answer:

> It was to match the space available in a handy kernel data structure.
>
> Quoting "The Design and Implementation of the 4.4BSD Operating System"
>   by McKusick et. al. (page 369):
>
> > The memory management facilities revolve around a data structure
> >     called an mbuf. Mbufs, or memory buffers, are 128 bytes long, with 100
> >     or 108 bytes of this space reserved for data storage.

**Other OSs(unix domain sockets):**

- [OpenBSD](http://man.openbsd.org/unix.4): 104 characters
- [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=unix&sektion=4): 104 characters
- [Mac OS X 10.9](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man4/unix.4.html): 104 characters

Comment: SUSv3 XNET was silent because there not consensus on the issue.

Comment: Do you have any link to proof your point of view?

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Is it reliable to use several socket files bearing identical names relative to different working directories (for instance, create a sockets file named `./my.socket` below directory `A/`, and another socket file also named `./my.socket` below directory `B/`)? `lsof` doesn't make any distinction between the two socket files, however it still seem to work but I wonder if this is just because I'm lucky. This would be a good workaround to create socket files below a path which is already longer than the allowed size.

Comment: Searching for unix sockets on my mailserver, seems to bring full path name: `lsof -U| grep amavis` (newline) `amavis-se  2708   zimbra   17u  unix 0xffff8806c0a95400      0t0 310330411 /opt/zimbra/data/tmp/amavisd-zmq.sock`

Comment: Yes, I know this is unusual, hence my question here ;) ! For what I tested, relative names work, but it still seems odd to me... but it works. My application is not system-wide, so socket files are either stored with all other application data in a user-controlled location, which is strongly preferred but with a potentially too long path, or I can clutter `/tmp` with tons of uniquely named undeleted directories each containing a single socket file (utterly ugly, but portable and secure).

Comment: You could shorten the name to `my.sock`  and you will have plenty of 101 characters to deal with :)

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf Not sure if this is part of the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard or not, but on Fedora at least the correct place for a user-specific named socket would be in `/run/user/<uid>/<appname>/my.socket`

Comment: @nwildner.   I was a voting member of XNET for a number of years.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 and i should trust that just because you are saying this? I cant even  check if you are a real person at your profile....
No offense, but if you don't have a link to make you theory valid, it will not be part of the answer.

Comment: Just a quick note to tell you I have investigated a bit the use of relative path for socket files (see my answer). Unless I missed something, it seems safe to me as, as per my understanding, the OS internally relies on inodes and not on path to identify the socket file.

Comment: @nwildner.  If you had bothered to look at my profile, you would have seen it contains a  link to my technical website which in turn contains a link to my LinkedIn profile.  You do have a LinkedIn account?  Then do an Internet search on my full name + "Single UNIX Specification"

Comment: Will i find any proof of what started this discussion? "SUSv3 XNET was sitent because there not consensus on the issue"...

Answer (score 8):

Regarding the why, nwildner already wrote an [excellent answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/367012/53965).

Here I will just focus on the how and the relative path usage.

Internally, while socket file can also be looked up by name (I guess), they are usually looked up by inode. In Linux, this lookup is ensured by the function `unix_find_socket_byinode()` defined in *net/unix/af_unix.c*.

This can be easily checked as follow:

- Create two directories *A/* and *B/*.
- Under each directory, make a process listen on socket files bearing the same name. With [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) you would use a command such as:

```
$ socat UNIX-LISTEN:./my.sock -
```

- Now exchange the socket files by moving *A/my.sock* to *B/* and vice-versa.
- From now on, if client application connects to *A/my.sock* it will contact the server *B*, and if it connects to *B/my.sock* it will contact the server *A* (note though that when the communication ends, the server process may legitimately delete what it thinks to be its own socket file).

I checked this behavior on a handful of Unix systems (Linux Debian, FreeBSD and OpenIndiana to get some diversity), so this behavior seems to be at least wide-spread, if not standard.

Absolute paths are usually used as a convention between the client and the server processes, as the client process may not otherwise know how to establish the initial communication with the server.

However, if this initial communication is not an issue, it seems therefore safe to use relative paths for socket files creation, allowing to avoid path length issues when the socket file location is not directly controlled by the server process.

Comment: no we would just need a "bind_at" system call that takes a cwd as a parameter. Touching the current working directory in a program sounds as evil and 1970s like Nixon and the use of the "select" syscall. Don't do it.  

I just checked that if i pass a longer path in my own structure (string with leading family does not help, the length is indeed checked. It shouldn't