# Does AF_INET required to create socket file?

Tags: tcp, socket

Question regarding creating the socket file for the `AF_INET`.

For `AF_UNIX` talking within the same host, we create socket file example `/tmp/name_of_the_socket_file`

How about `AF_INET`, does it requires socket file to be created?

AFAIK, I don't need to create socket file for `AF_INET` and I can communicate with simple client and server model.

My colleague told me I need to create socket file for the `AF_INET` with IP address as the file name, I don't understand that someone can clarify me?

Comment: What do you mean by "create a socket file" ? Are you talking about compiled code or scripts? Or anything else? Do you have code examples to discuss as a basis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My colleague told me I need to create socket file for the `AF_INET`

Your colleague is wrong. Taking a look at manpages of [`bind(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/bind) you can see that different socket types have rules:

> The rules used in name binding vary between address families. Consult
>   the manual entries in Section 7 for detailed information. For `AF_INET`,
>   see `ip(7)`; for `AF_INET6`, see `ipv6(7)`; for `AF_UNIX`, see `packet(7)`; for `AF_X25`, see `x25(7)`; and for `AF_NETLINK`, see `netlink(7)`.

You will see at [`ip(7)`](https://linux.die.net/man/7/ip) that there is no invocation involving `AF_INET` that can create a file. There is also this great [IBM paper](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/rzab6/cafinet.htm) about this socket structure and some history about it. Legacy structure form(BSD 4.4/Unix 98):

```
struct sockaddr_in {
  uint8_t         sin_len;
  sa_family_t     sin_family;
  u_short         sin_port;
  struct in_addr  sin_addr;
  char            sin_zero[8];
};
```

Current struct:

```
struct sockaddr_in {
    sa_family_t    sin_family; /* address family: AF_INET */
    in_port_t      sin_port;   /* port in network byte order */
    struct in_addr sin_addr;   /* internet address */
};

/* Internet address. */
struct in_addr {
    uint32_t       s_addr;     /* address in network byte order */
};
```

See, no mention of file creation whatsoever.

Quoting other part of [`ip(7)`](https://linux.die.net/man/7/ip) manpages about how this kind of socket(`AF_INET`) works:

> When a process wants to receive new incoming packets or connections,
>   it should bind a socket to a local interface address using `bind(2)`. In
>   this case, only one IP socket may be bound to any given local
>   (address, port) pair. When `INADDR_ANY` is specified in the bind call,
>   the socket will be bound to all local interfaces. When `listen(2)` is
>   called on an unbound socket, the socket is automatically bound to a
>   random free port with the local address set to `INADDR_ANY`. When
>   `connect(2)` is called on an unbound socket, the socket is automatically
>   bound to a random free port or to a usable shared port with the local
>   address set to `INADDR_ANY`.

--snip--

> **Address format**
>
> ***An IP socket address is defined as a combination of an IP interface***
>   ***address and a 16-bit port number.*** The basic IP protocol does not
>   supply port numbers, they are implemented by higher level protocols
>   like udp(7) and tcp(7). On raw sockets sin_port is set to the IP
>   protocol.

But if you look at [`unix(7)`](https://linux.die.net/man/7/unix) manpages you will see some examples of `AF_UNIX` socket type and its basic scructure. There is even a field called `sun_path` that is the path for socket files(see Related Stuff below):

```
#define UNIX_PATH_MAX    108

struct sockaddr_un {
  sa_family_t sun_family;               /* AF_UNIX */
  char        sun_path[UNIX_PATH_MAX];  /* pathname */
};
```

**tl,dr:** `AF_UNIX` is for sockets(and they use files) while `AF_INET` is for binding to ip addresses, and creating communications on its various forms(unicast, multicast, broadcast...).

**Related Stuff:**

- [example to explain unix domain socket - AF_INET vs AF_UNIX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21032562/2231796)
- [Why is socket path length limited to a hundred chars?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/367008/34720)

Comment: Thanks, @nwildner, but my colleague is not convinced what I said. Now I have the correct info and it clears my confusion.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer , Well, is up to him now to show you any software at github that uses `AF_INET` to create local files ;) It also does not makes sense in my mind why i would create a FILE with an IP adress on its name, if i can use the `localhost` address or `127.0.0.1` to deal with internal connections using  `AF_INET` if it is totally required by any sort of "internal software development law" :)

Comment: Unfortunately https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/rzab6/cafinet.htm is not available any more :(.